# Graphing Tool that allows for Manually entered X axis Points

Tags: calculator

I've been looking for ages and either cannot find the tool or figure out how...

I would like to plot a graph with the y=1/5(104-2(x/20+20/x)) but the graph with normal scaling is useless.

Log scaling of just the x axis could work, but what I am really looking for is a way to manually set the progression of the x axis. For instance, I would like to set 0,0, 20,0, and 1000,0, or something along those lines, at fixed intervals.

Does anyone know of a tool that will do this? Thank you!

EDIT: Ideally a Mac-compatible program or web tool. I cannot seem to do it in Numbers, Excel, or Grapher.

Comment: visit [Geogebra](https://geogebra.org/geometry) & see if it helps

Comment: What do you mean by "0,0, 20,0, and 1000,0"? If you're just looking for a normal graphing program where you can set the ticks, [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) is very good.

Comment: as in, with equal spacing on the x-axis, I would like to be able to set the first x marker at 0, the second at 20, and the third at 1000

Comment: You may find it more enlightening to substitute z=x/20+20/x and make a graph of y as a function of z, and then make a graph of z as a function of x.

Comment: @AlexanderEiden Oh, I see, I was reading $0,0$ as $x,y$-co-ordinates, but I think it's just the number $0$. Anyway, Desmos lets you set the spacing of tick marks.

Comment: @Théophile not variably to the best of my knowledge... not so first tick 0 second 20 third 1000

Comment: Ah, okay. Usually "fixed intervals" would mean with regular spacing, like every $20$ units. If you are comfortable using (or learning) Python, then here's a page describing how to set up custom tick marks: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.10-customizing-ticks.html